# Рекурсивное регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Помогите составить регулярку которая парсит текст от открывающего символа (слова) до закрывающего. К примеру взять HTML

```
<div>
    <div>...... </div>
    <div>......</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>...... </div>
    <div>......</div>
</div>
```

нужно что бы в match было

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А не:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и не:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пытался сам найти решение, вот есть регулярка

[http://codius.ru/articles/Парсим_HTML_Игнорирование_подобных_вложенных_конструкций_или_рекурсия_в_регулярных_выражениях](http://codius.ru/articles/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC_HTML_%D0%98%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

но она не работает в perl и на regex101.com 
все из-за конструкции

```
(?'-Open'</div>)
```

видимо движок в net позволяет такое делать. 
Есть еще несколько не рабочих примеров ))

https://studfiles.net/preview/2011809/page:121/
https://habr.com/post/50749/

Comment: Регекспы не предназначены для HTML. Используйте нормальные парсеры. Примеров здесь было - навалом.

Comment: Это ж как пример, что бы описать задачу, вместо div могут быть открывающиеся и закрывающиеся скобки

Comment: Без разницы. Используйте готовые парсеры или пишите свой. В любом случае условия размыты, может вообще задача сведётся к какому-нибудь банальному [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced)...

Comment: Спасибо, думаю Text::Balanced вполне подойдет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо именно регуляркой, то выйдет примерно так:

```
<div>          # Ищем div
(?: (?0)   |   # После которого идет все выражение целиком (?0), рекурсивно 
    [^<]++ |   # Или не начало тега, сверхжадный захват (можно не делать, но оно ускоряет)
    .          # Или любой символ
)*?            # и такое может быть сколько угодно раз (не жадно)
<\/div>        # Тег заканчивается
```

[Короткая версия](https://regex101.com/r/N2pPNi/1), без средств ускорения поиска `/<div>((?0)|.)*?<\/div>/s`. Если надо заключить все в группу захвата или за пределами блока поиска div будет еще что то, то можно ссылкаться на блок рекурсивно по номеру скобок, т.е. например как `(?1)`.

Так же, как заметил в комментариях [@PinkTux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194908/pinktux), для таких целей стоит использовать готовые модули, специально предназначенные для текстов определенного типа (например html или xml) или более простые модули для поиска сбалансированных частей текста, вроде [Text::Balanced](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Balanced)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @АртемАртемыч https://ideone.com/pBqNZi